# What are these yellow spots on my Melocactus concinnus?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, succulents, cactus

I purchased this Melocactus concinnus online a couple of months ago. I don't remember seeing those yellow spots on the bottom half of the cactus. It's possible, however, that I just didn't pay close attention. The spots are only on this side of the cactus. What could cause this, and is it a cause for concern?

[image: Melocactus concinnus]